# pdf font corruption in Inkscape and Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, inkscape, pdf

I'm trying to edit a PDF plot exported from Mathematica, using specific font `Times`  using the plot option `BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 10}`, to match with the LaTeX document I'm working on. but when I open it in Inkscape or Illustrator the font for numbers is corrupt:

- Inkscape:

[image]

- Illustrator

[image]

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is wrong and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The font in Mathematica is not recognized in Illustrator or Inkscape. Three possible solutions:

1. Switch to a common font in Mathematica and export again.
2. Install the Mathematica font on your system and the other programs should read it correctly.
3. Type it again in Illustrator.

Comment: I need specific fonts matching with my LaTeX document. I'm using `Times` which is already included in mac OS fonts, using the option `BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 10}` . what should I do?

Comment: Can you select the broken fonts in illustrator and switch them to Times? Does Mathematica have the option to embed fonts on export? Do you have .PDF saving options?  Can Mathematica export other file types? Maybe export the .PDF, open the PDF and copy paste the text from the PDF to Illustrator.

Comment: copy and pasting or retyping not good options as there a lot of them. I will look into the other options.

Comment: I found some clues on forums: Please go to Edit > Preferences > International section and let me know the value of the "Slect Font" dropdown.
 
Also, check whether the option "Use Local Fonts" is checked or not under the Page Display section in the Prefereneces dialog.

Comment: And Part 1: It sounds like Adobe is attempting to use its default fonts instead of the document's fonts. I was having a similar problem and the following fixed it for me (I'm using a Windows 7 Platform and Office 2010 Professional and was attempting to print a MapPoint Map to Adobe PDF in Adobe X.):

Comment: Part 2: 1. Click on START,DEVICES & PRINTERS, ADOBE PRINTER, PRINTER, PROPERTIES, PREFERENCES
2. Then under the AdobePDF Settings tab click on DEFAULT, HIGH QUALITY PRINT
Next, UN-CHECK “Rely on system fonts only, donot use document fonts.”
Click APPLY, OK

Comment: Part 3: 3. Go back to Step 1 andClick on the PAPER/QUALITY tab, ADVANCED
Lookfor IMAGE COLOR MANAGEMENT, TRUE TYPE FONT:
Clickon the “Substitute with device font.” A dropdown box will appear. Click on “DOWNLOAD AS SOFTFONT.”
4. Next, under DOCUMENT OPTIONS, click on POSTSCRIPT OPTIONS, TRUETYPE FONT DOWNLOAD OPTIONS:
Click on “Automatic.” A dropdown boxwill appear. Click on “NATIVE TRUETYPE.”
ClickOK to close the pop-up window. You may have to click on APPLY once youget back to the Paper/Quality tab, then click on OK to close that window.

Comment: I'm on mac OS @Webster :(

Comment: Part 4:  If Apply is available in the Adobe PDF Properties window, click it then clickOK one more time to close the window and “X” out of everything else. Yournew preferences should be saved and your document should print in Adobe just like it looks on your screen in the original program.   Found Here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/951202

Comment: Oh sorry. It looks like the Mac forums are full of solution suggestions as well. Basically getting the fonts to play nice with each other.

Comment: tried this: https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/40020-matlab-and-inkscape-times-new-roman-fonts-on-mac-os did not work though. could you please link any of those post you just said?

Comment: Link  at  bottom of part 4.

Comment: I can't see any mention to mac OS on that page

Comment: That result was from my search before including osx. I just searched for something like "PDF export weird symbols fix osx" then search the forums. It looks like a common problem with many solutions.